# Preventing jQuery from changing self-closing tags with custom XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm creating a browser plugin (bookmarklet) that exacts a large XML document embedded within the page's `<textarea>` element.  This is a custom XML language that includes a few self-closing tags (e.g., `<custom-tag />`). I'm able to capture the XML document, wrap it in a jQuery object variable (e.g., `$(myXml)`), and easily manipulate the data. However, after I try inserting the manipulated XML document back in the page's `<textarea>` element, all the self-closing tags are changed into separate opening and closing tags.  Here's an example of what's happening:

BEFORE:

```
<outer-tag>
    <SELF-CLOSING-TAG foo="bar" />
    <second-tag>
        <third-tag>Some Value</third-tag>
    </second-tag>
</outer-tag>
```

AFTER jQUERY MANIPULATION:

```
<outer-tag>
    <SELF-CLOSING-TAG foo="bar">
        <second-tag>
            <third-tag>Some Value</third-tag>
        </second-tag>
    </SELF-CLOSING-TAG>
</outer-tag>
```

Is there any way I can prevent jQuery (or is it just JavaScript or the browser?) from turning these self-closing tags into opening and closing tags?  This latter way is invalid for the XML schema we're using.  If there's no way around that, are there any other hacks worth considering?

UPDATE:
Drejc's ideas pointed me in the right direction to solve this issue.  After his input, I got the additional advice on this additional [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068431/how-to-use-javascript-to-loop-through-a-long-string-to-insert-a-new-string-after/8068766#8068766) and together this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked when this happens. After inserting a new element or after read out. You might give it a try with no self closing elements, like this:

```
<outer-tag>
    <SELF-CLOSING-TAG foo="bar"></<SELF-CLOSING-TAG>
    <second-tag>
        <third-tag>Some Value</third-tag>
    </second-tag>
</outer-tag>
```

It might help.

Comment: This happens regardless of whether or not I actually make any changes myself to the XML.  This happens automatically when I extract the XML via jQuery and then use jQuery again to place (the same) XML back on the page. This is a custom XML language my company uses, and I have no way around using the self-closing tags.  Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Drejc, after further consideration, your idea of placing the closing tag immediately after the opening tag (for the self-closing tags) could work and would be valid XML. However, I don't see how to easily automate that work.  There are ~ 30 different types of self-closing tags and the XML documents are 3,000+ lines long.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with jQuery in combination with XML, but there might be some option on one or the other side to force that self closing element are rendered as empty elements. I know C# can do this. But it sounds to me as a bug in jQuery, try conntacting the jQuery team about it.

Answer (score 0):

This "feels like" the result of an XSD definition that requires your self-closing tag to wrap around the "second-tag".  Give that a look.  I'm also suspicious this might not happen if you try a different browser.

Comment: I tried this in different browsers and the result is the same.  I'm not sure which XSD the browser would be referencing.  Is there any way I can force jQuery (or the browser) to reference a specific XSD?