# How to use JavaScript to loop through a long string to insert a new string after every match

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, loops

I have a variable that contains a long string that represents an XML document.  Within that string, I need to search for every self-closing tag and expand into two matching opening/closing tags.  I'm really not sure how to tackle this and would appreciate your advice.  At this point, all I know is how to match a self-closing tag via regex: `[^<]+?/>`   Here's a short example of what I would like to accomplish:

ORIGINAL STRING:

```
<outer-tag>
    <inner-tag-1>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-1 foo="bar"/>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-2/>
    </inner-tag-1>
    <inner-tag-2>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-3 attr="value"/>
    </inner-tag-2>
</outer-tag>
```

MODIFIED STRING:

```
<outer-tag>
    <inner-tag-1>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-1 foo="bar"></SELF-CLOSING-TAG-1>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-2></SELF-CLOSING-TAG-2>
    </inner-tag-1>
    <inner-tag-2>
        <SELF-CLOSING-TAG-3 attr="value"></SELF-CLOSING-TAG-3>
    </inner-tag-2>
</outer-tag>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [w3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) to create a regexp which correctly parses tags in well-formed XML.

First, select the characters which define the start-tag (per specs). Then, match the remaining characters, excluding possibly trailing spaced and `/>`. Globally replace the matched substrings by
`"<" + starttag + remaining + "></" + starttag + ">"`. See below:

```
//According to the W3 spec: 
var pattern = /<([:A-Z_a-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02FF\u0370-\u037D\u037F-\u1FFF\u200C-\u200D\u2070-\u218F\u2C00-\u2FEF\u3001-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFFD][-.0-9\xB7\u0300-\u036F\u0203F-\u2040]*)([^>]*?)\s*?\/>/g;
string.replace(pattern, '<$1$2></$1>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```js
the_string.replace(/< *(\w+)([^<\/>]*)\/>/g, "<$1$2></$1>")
```

Explanation:

```
   <          opening tag
   ' *'       ignore whitespace
$1 (\w+)      tag name (remember at $1)
$2 ([^<\/>]*) attributes (remember at $2)
   \/>        close tag
```

Comment: This works very well and does solve the problem.  The only improvement would be to prevent the above regex from adding a space at the end of each opening tag.  Thanks for your help.